# Questions about SharePoint App bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, sharepoint-app-bar

The SharePoint App bar is a bit confusing to me as the site admin and to the end users, where it is not clear what each section is trying to show. Here are our three issues/questions:-

1. The "My Sites" >> "Frequent" section, what should it show exactly ? "Frequent" means the sites that i have accessed frequently ? because some sites which get listed to the users were never accessed by that user?

[image]

2. For all users the "My News" section will keep loading forever

[image]

3. For the "My Lists" and "My Documents" sections, what is exactly meant by "Recent"? recently added/modified by any user or recently accessed/viewed by the login user?

Can anyone advice on my above 3 question please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft documentation for [App bar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-sharepoint-app-bar-b2ab82d5-9af7-445e-ad24-236c5a86b5f8?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), each section represents the below:

**My sites** – See sites that you frequently visit and sites that you follow.

**My news** – Review curated news based on your activity and interests.

**My files** – View and access files that you’ve recently been working on.

**My lists** – See lists that you've recently viewed or your favorite lists.

You can find how the sites you follow works under [Sites you Follow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-follow-sites-news-and-content-4411e38f-9bc5-4ecc-bd33-3dbe939ac84c) link.

As mentioned above link, these suggestions are based on user interaction and recommendations from the Microsoft Graph.